# PHP counting records from other table using id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table prices that looks like this:

> id - price - amount

I have an other table winners that keeps what price the users have won. It looks like this:

> id - userid - priceid

So the id of my table prices is the sale as the priceid in the winners table.

Now let's say I want the amount of winners that have won price X and price X has id 1 for example. I've tried writing a query but it doesn't seem to make much sense.

```
$price = "X";
$count = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT winners.id FROM winners INNER JOIN prices ON winners.priceid=prices.id WHERE prices.price='".$price."'");
```

If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it very much

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up tutorials with mysql `JOIN`

Comment: @Epodax hey thanks for your response I forgot all about joins lol, I updated my question with an inner join query but it still doesn't seem to be working, unfortunately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding SUM() to mySQL JOIN query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447596/adding-sum-to-mysql-join-query)

Comment: Also keep in mind the potential risks of concatenating SQL strings (SQL injection threats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number that have won price X :

```
$count = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT COUNT(winners.id) AS nb_winners FROM winners INNER JOIN prices ON winners.priceid=prices.id WHERE prices.price='".$price."'");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! I was close :)

Comment: But I have a little problem when I dump $count I get something like this "count_winners":"1" I only need the number because I do a check if($amount>$count)

Comment: You can do that : if($amount > $count->count_winners), or you might directly get the number, but that depends of what db library you are using.